# Why is my Lubuntu desktop environment changed to LXQt after upgrading from 18.04 to 18.10?

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, lxde, lxqt, 18.10

I had a fresh installation of Lubuntu 18.04 (no upgrade) and upgraded to 18.10 today. Afterwards I was booted into a graphical user interface that does not look like Lubuntu. My settings for the panel are gone.

When logging in I have four options for desktop environments:

- LXQt
- Lubuntu
- Openbox
- Plasma

When I chose Lubuntu I have this new look. Chosing LXQt looks the same, but is not exactly the same (e.g. different panel content). Openbox leads to a black screen where I can use the right mouse to open a context menu that looks a bit like a start menu.

How can I get Lubuntu desktop back?

Comment: As I learned from some reading LXQt seems to be the default now for Lubuntu 18.10. If this is true I want to change back to 18.04.

Comment: I read a comment here about changing back to LXDE by logging out. There is no such option. Last option in the menu is "Plasma".

Comment: If you don't like LXQt, you'll need to re-install Lubuntu 18.04. There's no other way to "change back".

Comment: Why is my question downvoted? I had a perfect installation of LUBUNTU 18.04 and was suggested an upgrade to 18.10 by my system. I was of course expecting an upgrade to a Lubuntu version, not another distribution.

Comment: No idea. Downvoters are not obliged to explain. It would be useful sometimes but other times giving reasons could lead to argument?

Comment: I think my question is relevant and correct. If you are not an experienced or involved user and just upgrade your stuff as suggested, like all the other times, this change comes as a surprise. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I suspect the downvoting is due to the rather ranty flavor of the last two paragaphs. How to revert your system to 18.04 look-and-feel using an 18.04 LiveUSB is well known, so you might be getting downvoted for that, too. (I did not vote either way).

Answer (score 8):

Lubuntu's move to LXQt has been well-publicised. See the lead developer's post [here](https://lubuntu.me/taking-a-new-direction/) from July 2018.

> For the forseeable future, here are our core goals:
>
> Lubuntu will leverage modern, Qt-based technologies and programs to give users a functional yet modular experience.
>   In collaboration with others, Lubuntu will continue to be a transparent and open distribution which makes it a priority to keep the community informed about the development when possible.
>   Lubuntu will create and maintain complete documentation which will be included by default in the operating system, and can guide anyone from beginner to expert on how to use Lubuntu to its full potential and contribute to the further development of it.
>   Lubuntu will keep a light experience by default but enable users to utilize more heavy and featureful components as desired.
>   Lubuntu will have the ability to be used in any language across the world, and enable contributors to easily translate all components of the operating system.

In any case, Lubuntu 18.04 LTS will be supported [until April 2021](https://lubuntu.me/bionic-released/).

More, older reading:

- From May 2018: https://news.softpedia.com/news/hands-on-with-first-lubuntu-18-10-build-featuring-the-lxqt-desktop-by-default-521200.shtml

Comment: When I have a Lubuntu distribution and it suggests an upgrade to another version, I don't expect another desktop environment. I also don't think, that this one post is characterized correctly by naming it "well-publicised". There is no way for a user that is not involved to understand, that this means the GUI is going to change so much.

Comment: I cited one post. There are many, many more. At one time it was a standing joke that Lubuntu would never make the transition. I understand your feeling, but it really was planned a long, long time ago.

Comment: @Ben It wasn't just one post, it's been tens if not hundreds of posts over the span of the last twoish years.

Comment: `I don't expect another desktop environment` when you upgrade the OS, the whole thing with it will be upgraded as long as old apps continue to work. For example in Ubuntu the desktop environment was changed from GNOME to Unity and back to GNOME3 in 18.04LTS. Similarly in Vista MS introduced a "breaking" change from a traditional desktop to a compositional one with DWM